How do I fix a "focus text field error" in Power Automate when trying to capture fillable elements of a PDF form?
I have a flow that works in conjunction with Adobe Acrobat Reader to automate the process of filling a blank DIR-12 form with a list of DIN's taken from an excel file and stored in a variable.
The flow takes each DIN, inputs it into the appropriate field on the form, and then presses a button to gather the information generated, which is then stored into a new excel.
However, I'm encountering an error that is probably quite a simple fix. I'm using the focusing Text field action, and the issue is that it doesn't recognise one particular field at a time. Instead I get a block encompassing all the fields, which is not ideal. And the issue arises every time I close and open the PDF.
Appreciate any inputs on how to fix this
I tried using the Send Keys action but it didn't work as I expected

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
